# Vb.Net select tables

Tags: vb.net

I am new in Vb.NET and I have a code here which I got from example, which select one table. What I want is I want to select another tABLe.. I just want to select another table other than users.. since I have a another form which binds/call another table.

How will I do it?

```
Dim connection As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
    Dim adapter As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim commandBldr As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommandBuilder
    Dim command As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
    Dim dataSet As System.Data.DataSet
    Dim bindingSource1 As BindingSource

    Private Sub btConnect_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btConnect.Click
        connection = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
        connection.ConnectionString = "user id=" & tbUserName.Text + "; password=" & tbPassword.Text & "; server=" & tbServer.Text & "; database=" & tbDatabase.Text & "; pooling=false;"

        Try
            connection.Open()
            adapter = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter
            commandBldr = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommandBuilder
            command = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
            dataSet = New System.Data.DataSet
            bindingSource1 = New BindingSource

            commandBldr.DataAdapter = adapter
            command.CommandText = "SELECT userID,pin, print1, print2 from users"
            command.Connection = connection
            adapter.SelectCommand = command
            adapter.Fill(dataSet)
            bindingSource1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables(0)
            dgvUsers.DataSource = bindingSource1

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
```

I got it by doing this...

```
dataSet = New DataSet
adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "select * from dtr"
adapter.Fill(dataSet)
```

Comment: do you want to bring back two different tables, or just select a different table then users?

Comment: i just want to select another table other than users..since i have a another form which calls another table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to change the command text of your example query to match what you want to pull back. For example:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT col1, col2 from newTable"
```